# CRM OData DateTime Timezone Issue

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am running into an issue where CRM doesn't appear to be treating the DateTime correctly with OData.  Specifically, we are trying to create a custom record called new_vod with a start and end time (and a few other attributes that I have removed from here for simplicity) using a JavaScript call to the CrmRestKit.  When the user performing this function is not in the same time zone as the server, the time is incorrect by whatever the offset between the server and the user happens to be.

For example, if my CRM user is in Mountain Time and the Server is in Eastern Time, the Start Time will be 2 hours from now (even though it should be now) when looking at the newly created record in CRM.  The user's computer's timezone doesn't seem to have any impact on the result.  (I'm comparing the "new_starttime" against the "Created On" time to confirm I'm not just viewing the data wrong, and the created on time is 2 hours before the start time in this scenario).

Here is the relevant snippet:

```
var startTime = new Date();

//Add 90 minutes to the current date/time
var endTime = new Date();
endTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() + 90);

//Create a cvt_VOD record
var newVOD = {
    'new_starttime': startTime,
    'new_endtime': endTime
};

var createdVOD = CrmRestKit.Create('new_vod', newVOD)
...
```

I noticed that when I debug the create of the new_vod record in a pre-stage plugin, the "conversion" to UTC has already occurred incorrectly, so it leads me to believe that the Rest Call itself isn't right.

Can anyone shed any light on why this would be happening?

FYI, We're on CRM 2015 on-premise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this working solution by Somesh:

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmbestpractices/archive/2014/12/04/crm-timezone-issue-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I saw this page when I was originally looking into the issue.  It is incomplete in my opinion.  The function that seems to be doing the core of the work accepts an input parameter called "currentAccount", and the DateTime value of that parameter seems to already be converted.  I want to see how that conversion is done.  The other shortcoming is that this solution asks a user to select a DateTime without any timezone as opposed to programmatically getting the time right now.

Comment: I'm a little unclear what the suggestion is here.  There's 3 alerts, so I tried putting the values that go into those alerts to replace the startDate and EndDate.  my results: the first one is what I have been trying, so that was the same result, the second alert ended up with the same result, and the third one resulted in a time that was off by a number of hours.

Comment: Basically the CRM server context takes the date time you passed & convert to UTC to store in DB. If you are passing the date time from client side using datetime.now will take what the machine settings are. So you have to reverse engineer it to match with server time. I gave the jsfiddle to play around .toISOString() & .getTimezoneOffset() to reverse engineer what you want. Clear?